# Unable to run on non-Dell system

Tags: 18.04, dell, asus

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on Asus X550V, downloaded from the official website. The installation processes went all without any errors.
After starting Ubuntu, I updated it, then restarted the PC. When it started, it hangs on the boot screen with this error: `Unable to run on non-Dell system`
I rebooted it again and opened **Advanced options for Ubuntu** on *grub* then I chose to boot on an old kernel `4.15.0-20-generic` (The latest kernel in my PC is `4.15.0-23-generic`). The PC started without any errors.
But when I run `dmesg`, I encountered the following errors:

```
[    1.162410] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
[    1.162426] MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
[    1.418512] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 612004 [ IBUS ]
[    1.425953] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 10ac08 [ IBUS ]
[   11.168848] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80
[   11.168912] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80
[   12.771862] dell_smbios: Unable to run on non-Dell system
```

**That seems very strange to get an error about Dell in an Asus PC.

Is there any explanation and solution for this?**
PS: The PC has an Nvidia GTX 950M graphic card.

Comment: You need to install Nvidia drivers. That message is not related to the problem.

Comment: Where did you download from ?

Answer (score 3):

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Precision T5500, and also receive `dell_smbios: Unable to run on non-Dell system` from the kernel. The system seems to run perfectly normal. I believe that the message is coming from libsmbios. `libsmbios-c2` was installed automatically. It is provided by Dell, and is looking for vendor specific BIOS extensions.

It appears that this is not a critical error, and may be treated like a warning message.